# Control.OnKeyDown triggered by Logitech mouse?

Tags: c#, mousewheel, onkeydown, logitech

In my C# application, I handle <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> in `OnKeyDown` as shown below. It works as intented. However, when I press the middle button on my Logitech M705 I get a sequence of unwanted key events. *Both* `foo()` and `bar()` get called, which clearly is unwanted behavior. (I suppose the driver generates several key presses to activate some special zoom tool?)

**Q:** How can I detect these simulated key presses? Or, how can I prevent `OnKeyDown` from being called in this particular case?

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ShiftKey)
        foo();
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.ControlKey)
        bar();
}
```

Comment: Do you have any macros set in the Logitech software?

Comment: I have the default settings in Logitech `SetPoint`. No macros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like your logitec driver has a certain key combination macro bound to your middle button click.  Since the driver intentionally simulates keyboard input, I'm not sure it's possible to filter out "fake" keypresses.

Comment: I suppose it can be done using an application-wide `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` hook and check for the `LLKHF_INJECTED` flag. Ugh... :/

Comment: If the mouse presents itself as multiple HID devices, this may actually be being done in hardware - in which case the LLKHF_INJECTED flag won't be present. I know this is certainly the case with the G9 and similar.

Comment: Thanks for the info. No solution then... :/